# How can I understand など followed by a noun phrase?

Tags: grammar

The following two sentences are from 日本語文法ハンドブック, page 116:

> 移動を表す表現にはいくつかありますが、「行く」と「来る」は補助動詞としての用法を持つ点で文法的に重要です。補助動詞としての「〜ていく」と「〜てくる」（この場合は普通ひらがなで書きます）には、**話し手など文中の特定の人物の視点を**基準にした空間的な移動の方向性を示す用法と、特定
>   の時点からの出来事の時間的推移や展開のとらえ方を表す用法があります。

My question is about `など`.  From context, it seems like the phrase `話し手など` is modifying the following phrase, `文中の特定の人物の視点`.

I'm a little confused, though. *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar* (p.268) states that "[a] particle normally follows *nado*", so when I read this sentence, I was expecting some kind of particle after `など` to indicate the role played by `話し手など`.  Instead, `など` was followed by a noun phrase!  As a result, I don't know what role `話し手など` plays in the sentence.

**How can I understand `など` followed by a noun phrase?**

My guesses:

1. `N1などN2` = "N2 such as N1"
2. There is some sort of particle deleted after `など`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first guess is right. N1などN2 is "N2 such as N1" or "N2 (for example N1)"

When we say など is followed by a particle, such as N1などが, it should be probably thought of as a suffix decoration to a noun, as in "N1 (and several other things like N1)"

Comment: Is の optional after など when used in this way? I've seen sentences which went N1やN2などN3 and N1やN2などのN3 which both meant "N3 such as N1 or N2".