# Confusing clause in middle of sentence

Tags: grammar, syntax

In the following sentence:

> 彦一｛ひこいち｝さんがのこった荷物を見たときは、**皆の握り飯が入っているお弁当など**重そうなものしか残っていませんでした。

I don't understand how the part in bold fits into the sentence. Without that part I have

> When 彦一 saw the remaining baggage (stuff in bold) there were only heavy looking things left.

The bit in bold I think is "bento boxes containing everyone's rice balls and the like". How does that fit with the rest of the sentence? Is it just a parenthetical statement describing the baggage that 彦一 saw?

I recently came across [this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/how-to-express-appositives-in-japanese) which suggested similar constructs were not possible. Under what circumstances can I use such a construction. For example could I say "If bob goes to Tuvalu -- a small island in the Pacific ocean -- he will need to take a towel" using the same grammar? Here's my attempt:

> ボブはTuvaluに行くなら、太平洋にある小さな島タオルがひつようだ。

Comment: If anyone can think of a better question title to describe the content I will gladly change it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I understand など followed by a noun phrase?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/)

Comment: That makes sense thanks. Looks like I was completely of the mark. Can I assume that my towel sentence is utter nonsense then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[彦一]{ひこいち}さんがのこった[荷物]{にもつ}を[見]{た}たときは、**[皆]{みな}の[握]{にぎ}り[飯]{めし}が[入]{はい}っているお[弁当]{べんとう}など**[重]{おも}そうなものしか[残]{のこ}っていませんでした。」

The part in **bold** only gives an example of the 「重そうなもの」.

**≒** 「重そうなもの」 such as 「皆の握り飯が入っているお弁当」

My own TL: ***"When Hikoichi saw the remaining belongings, there was nothing but some heavy-looking stuff like everyone's riceballs left."***

Moving on...

Your sentence 「ボブはTuvaluに[行]{い}くなら、[太平洋]{たいへいよう}にある[小]{ちい}さな[島]{しま}タオルがひつようだ。」 makes almost no sense after the comma, I am afraid.

You can say:

> 「ボブは、太平洋にある小さな島、ツバルに行くなら、タオルがひつようだ。」 or
>
> 「ボブは、太平洋にある小さな島『ツバル』に行くなら、タオルがひつようだ。」